# How does signal scaling affects stationary wavelet?

Tags: wavelet

I'm currently working on some signals recorded with different sensors with different adc resolutions. I wonder how this different resolutions affect signal's stationary wavelet. Does it just changes the amplitudes or does it affect it's pattern too?

Answer (score 1):

Stationary wavelet transforms are not in general [equivariant](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/16060/what-is-the-difference-between-equivariant-to-translation-and-invariant-to-tr/16084#16084) to scaling in the data, unless the actual scale-ratio between to signals is a power of the discrete wavelet basic resolution change (classically a power-of-two).

Comparing two signals at non-rational sample rates is a bit tricky, however you can spot differences in the picture below, especially at the finest scale:[image: Comparing differently scaled signals and the stationary wavelet coefficients SWT]

Meanwhile, if the signals are smooth enough, and if you lock as complex coefficients, that could be fine enough for many practical purposes.

```
myScaledFunction = @(t) double((abs(t)<0.85)).*(1./sqrt(0.001+abs(t-0.31).*abs(t-0.61)));
 nSample1 = 77;
 nSample2 = 97;
% nSample1 = 99;
% nSample2 = 117;
nSamplePad = 128;
time1 = linspace(0,1,nSample1)';
time2 = linspace(0,1,nSample2)';
data1 = myScaledFunction(time1); 
data2 = myScaledFunction(time2); 
data1Pad = [data1;zeros(nSamplePad-nSample1,1)];
data2Pad = [data2;  zeros(nSamplePad-nSample2,1)];
close all
subplot(2,2,1)
plot(data1Pad,'.')
subplot(2,2,2)
imagesc(swt(data1Pad,3,'haar'));
subplot(2,2,3)
plot(data2Pad,'.')
subplot(2,2,4)
imagesc(swt(data2Pad,3,'haar'));
```